# Как преобразовать строку в дату, используя при этом несколько шаблонов дат?

Tags: java, дата

У меня есть строка с датой, которая может иметь следующий вид(заранее не известный): дд.мм.гг, дд.мм.гггг или дд/мм/гг. Как её преобразовать в дату(использую класс LocalDate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", locale);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", locale);
```

Форматировать дату:

```
Date date = new Date();
String result1 = dateFormat1.format(date);
String result2 = dateFormat2.format(date);
System.out.println(result1);
System.out.println(result2);
```

Получить дату из строки:

```
Date date1 = dateFormat1.parse("2019-29-01");
Date date2 = dateFormat2.parse("...");
```

Вероятно вот то, что Вы ищите:

```js
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Dates {

    static SimpleDateFormat[] formats = new SimpleDateFormat[] {
        new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy"),
        new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"),
        new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy")
    };

    static Date parse(String date) {
        for (SimpleDateFormat format : formats) {
            try {
                return format.parse(date);
            } catch (ParseException ignored) {}
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(parse("29.10.83"));
        System.out.println(parse("29.10.1983"));
        System.out.println(parse("29/10/83"));
    }
}
```

Ну и может вернутся `null`, если ни один формат не подойдет

Comment: Мне надо из строки получить дату, а не наоборот

Comment: У меня есть строка даты, которая имеет один из этих шаблонов: дд.мм.гг, дд.мм.гггг или дд/мм/гг. Но я не знаю заранее, какой из них будет использоваться

Comment: @damn дополнил ответ еще раз

Answer (score 0):

Если уж использовать java.time, то лучше так

```
static DateTimeFormatter[] formats = new DateTimeFormatter[] {
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yy"),
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"),
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy")
    };

    static LocalDate parse(String date) {
        for (DateTimeFormatter format : formats) {
            try {
                return LocalDate.parse(date, format);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException ignored) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Автор ведь говорит, что юзает LocalDate...